# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'STATE_PENDING' MAGENTO

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have this code

```
$updateOrder->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING, true);
$updateOrder->save();
```

The error is

`Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'STATE_PENDING' in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no   constant `STATE_PENDING` in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class.  It's `STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT`.

Change your code to this:

```
$updateOrder->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

the class don't have pending state. I think you can use STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT

```
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```